# Android - change color of a button for a certain time

Tags: java, android

Some expert tell me why this code doesn't work, the purpose is simple to change the color of a button for a certain period of time, after that period you must color returns to original color. The problem is that is not run in order, should be a button to change the color, wait 1s, back to original color then the same for the next button to complete the sequence.

Sorry my bad English and thanks in advance.

```
    int temp[] = new int[game.getLevel()];
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    temp = game.getSequence();
    for(int i = 0; i < game.getLevel(); i++)
    {
        switch (temp[i])
        {
            case RED:
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 

                              redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
                         } 
                    }, 1000); 
                redButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(109, 0, 0));
                break;

            case GREEN:

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                              greenButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
                         } 
                    }, 1000); 
                 greenButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 109, 0));
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                              yellowButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
                         } 
                    }, 1000); 
                 yellowButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(109, 109, 0));
                break;
            case BLUE:
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                              blueButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
                         } 
                    }, 1000); 
                 blueButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use message queue:

```
static final int RED = 0;
static final int GREEN = 1;
static final int YELLOW = 2;
static final int BLUE = 3;

mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(RED, 1000);
            }
        });

mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (msg.what) {
                case RED:
                    mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(GREEN, 1000);
                    break;
                case GREEN:
                    mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(YELLOW, 1000);
                    break;
                case YELLOW:
                    mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(BLUE, 1000);
                    break;
                case BLUE:
                    mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(RED, 1000);
                    break;
                }

            }
        };
```